# Set Kinect v2 frame rates (rgb, depth, skeleton) to 25 fps

Tags: c++, visual-studio, kinect-v2

I'm working on a project which requires all three streams from the Kinect v2 sensor (RGB, Depth, and Skeleton) to be captured, processed and streamed at 25 fps. 
My program works with default settings and all three streams seem to be operating at 30fps. Is there a method to reduce this to 25 fps?.

I'm working on a C++ environment.

Comment: I observed that adding delay prior to acquiring a frame can help to reduce the frame rate. I have a feeling that this is not the best approach but seem to do the trick. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

The KINECT SDK offers no way of setting the frame rate. Moreover, the RGB frame rate is not fixed and may drop down to 15 fps (from 30 fps) in low light conditions. Your approach of adding delay does not change the native frame rate of the devices. All you are doing is selectively dropping some frames based on timing. If regular spacing between frame capture times is important to your application you should be implementing an interpolation method instead.